# Tomcat 8.5 w/Java 8 and openssl 1.0.1: Can't get port 8443 to respond

Tags: ssl, tomcat

Hoping for some help getting the SSL 8443 port to accept https connections.  Have the following setup:

```
CentOS: 2.6.32-220.el6.i686
Java:       1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-3.b14.el6_8.i386
OpenSSL:    1.0.1e-48.el6_8.1
Tomcat: 8.5.4
Apr-devel:  1.5.2
```

- used keytool to setup a 2048 bit keystore with self-signed
  certificate
- generated the CSR and sent to CA
- imported the return from the CA along with root and chain

I have had no luck configuring the Connector for port 8443 with the above software.

I attempted to use the Tomcat 6/7 syntax to associate the Connector to the keystore with no luck.  In the docs, it states that 8.5 will use the old syntax and build a `SSLHostconfig` stanza in the background:

Old syntax:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
        maxThreads="200" compression="on"
        scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true">
        keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/.keystore" keyAlias="tomcat"
        keystorePass="changeit"
```

....

The password given in the Connector is the same as that defi `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol` need for both the keystore and the self signed certificate.  Using the above I either get a hang forever on access to 8443 or the server returns keystore tampered with or bad password.

I've also tried the above but using the `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"`, and Nio2.

Example error message:

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio-8443"]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

.. with the same results (hang or password error).

New syntax:
I've tried all sorts of combinations of entries/attributes  of the SSLHostConfig object with no joy.  It either just throws Java errors at startup or hangs on access (no password errors here as I don't even think it is attempting to hit the keystore ).

Can anyone here suggest a route to get 8443 up on Tomcat 8.5 w/Java 8 on CentOS 6?

Can anyone here suggest a method to test whether the Certificate and chain are installed correctly?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: apr uses openssl. openssl can't use a java keystore. Read the documentation once more.

Comment: Are you uising JKS keystore? the APR connector requires PEM encoded certificates, not JKS. It also requires using the APR configuration parameters.